# xcode iphone prevent app from backgrounding?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

How can I prevent my app from backgrounding? When I press the home button the app does not seem to close but save its state. Do I have to add some code to `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:`?

Comment: What is your question? Are you trying to prevent your app from being sent to the background or are you wanting to terminate it instead of putting it to sleep?

Comment: near duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127560/how-do-i-tell-ios-that-i-do-not-want-the-app-to-stay-in-the-background/6127598#6127598

Comment: It is not adviced to change the functionality of the home button. Apple will likely not accept your app in the store. just so you know:)

Comment: The language of iOS development is Objective-C, not C++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you are referring to preventing the application from Running in the Background?

This is controlled via the application's Info.plist.

Add:

`Application does not run in background` setting it to `YES`

or in XML

`<key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
    <true/>`

Answer (score 1):

If you mess around with the home button's functionality Apple will NOT allow your app in the store. I tried to do the same thing but the app got rejected with reason: "The Home button's functionality is absolute and should not be changed without a valid reason.".